# If a series converges, does the sequence of its summands necessarily converge to zero?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

A sequence is defined as $a_{1}, a_{2}, ... $, and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.  Is it necessarily true that $ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty } a_{n} = 0$?

I don't know where to begin. It seems intuitively true but I've come across enough non-intuitive results to stop taking that at face value. I can also show that the converse is definitely not true.

Comment: Can you be more precise about "which sums to a constant number"?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n$ converges?

Comment: Yes you're right, my bad...

Comment: The answer to you question (if I have understood it correctly) is yes.  This result is proven in pretty much any calculus textbook which discusses series.

Comment: For example http://www.nabla.hr/CL-SeriesA1.htm ... from "... it is necessary condition for the convergence of a series ..."

Answer (score 1):

If $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$, then the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ exists and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n-A_{n-1}=0$. But them$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}(A_n-A_{n-1})=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n.$$

Answer (score 0):

If the partial sums converge to $L$, they differ from $L$ by less than your favourite $\epsilon>0$, provided you go far enough in. But each term is a difference of two partial sums, so will be $<2\epsilon$. So yes, they do go to $0$.